# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'xyzzy'

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I am declaring a nested object, I am not sure about the number of keys(random1, random2, random3), but I know the structure inside, an example:

```
const sampleObject: koInfoType = {
random1: {hcp: 9, homePrice: 6, awayPrice: 3, goalLine: 2, overPrice: 9, underPrice: 1},
random2: {hcp: 1, homePrice: 4, awayPrice: 23, goalLine: 78, overPrice: 4, underPrice: 5},
......
}
```

I am declaring the type as `koInfoType`.

```js
interface koStatType {
  hcp?: number;
  homePrice?: number;
  awayPrice?: number;
  goalLine?: number;
  overPrice?: number;
  underPrice?: number;
}


interface koInfoType {
  [key: string]: koStatType
}
```

I got the error when I assign the nested value into it, where am I doing wrong?

```js
newKoInfo[random1][underPrice] = 3
```

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'koStatType'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'koStatType'.
```

Comment: What's the value of underPrice? It's type is string, so maybe you should narrow it down to the keys of koStatType

Comment: It's type should be number. @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Comment: @TungTung - I'm removing my comment, since it was frivolous :p ... *plugh* ... it's gone

Comment: Could you [edit] to show the `forEach()` you need to support?  A [mre] ideally shows all the parts needed to test a potential answer.

Answer (score 0):

//use string or string literals

newKoInfo["random1"]["underPrice"] = 3

Comment: Both of `random` and `underPrice` should be variable inside `forEach`, that's why I won't know the numbers of the keys

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).